# How to enable Security Logging AX2012 (SecurityTasks to SecurityRoles)

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to log `SecurityRole` - `SecurityTask` changes, and since the `EeUserRoleChangeLog` logs `User` – `SecurityRole` changes (for Estonia, but commenting out language detection, it logs also for us here in Holland perfectly). I think that basis can be used to log those changes.

So I first created the table:
`EeRoleTaskChangeLog` with the following fields:
`AddRemove` EnumType: `AddRemove`
`ChangedBy` EDT: `UserID`
`SecurityRole` EDT: `RefRecID`
`SecurityTask` EDT: `RefRecId`

I then noticed that within the class `SysSecRole`, User-Role changes logging is triggered within method `removeFromSelectedUser`. So whenever someone changes something from the AOT or the front-end, all these changes are then logged within the `EeUserRoleChangeLog`.

So I extended `SysSecTask` with the method `removeFromSelectedRole`:

```
public void removeFromSelectedRole() 
{
    RefRecId                    SecurityRole;       
    SysSecTreeTasks             taskTree;          
    SecurityRoleTaskGrant       SecurityRoleTaskGrant;  

    taskTree = tree as SysSecTreeTasks; 
    securityRole = taskTree.getSecurityRole(); 

    ttsbegin;

    EePersonalDataAccessLogging::logRoleTaskChange(recId, 0, securityRole, AddRemove::Remove);

    delete_from securityRoleTaskGrant where securityRoleTaskGrant.SecurityRole == securityRole && securityRoleTaskGrant.SecurityTask == recId;

    ttscommit;

    if (treeControl)
    {
        tree.deleteTreeItem(treeControl, idx);
    }
    }
```

However, it somehow doesn’t recognize the triggers and so it does not fill my table.
I hoped to add a delete/insert trigger to the `SecuryRoleTaskGrant` systemtable, but this is completely closed, so I have no idea how or where this method can be triggered.

So then I thought as a ‘semi-working’ work around, let’s only log changes made in the front-end, since that already fixes the problem for the regular workers. So I decided to find a similar trigger within Forms, and I found the form `SysSecUserAddRoles` with method `assignRolesToSelectedUser`. This method has the following trigger:

```
    if (added)
    {
        EePersonalDataAccessLogging::logUserRoleChange(secRole.RecId,0, userId, AddRemove::Add);
    }
```

I decided to add this trigger to a Form that allows workers to change Task-Roles: `SysSecRoleAddTasks` method `addTasksFromRole`, and somehow this also does not seem to fix the problem. It doesn’t fill the table. I use the following code, and front-end changes are still not logged within my created `EeRoleTaskChangeLog` table.

```
public int addTasksFromRole(SecurityRole _role, boolean _recursive = false)
{
    SecurityRole childRole;
    SecuritySubRole subRole;
    SecurityTask task;
    SecurityRoleTaskGrant srtGrant;
    int nAdded = 0;
    RefRecId    securityRole;
    boolean             added;

    if (_role.RecId == targetRoleId)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    startLengthyOperation();
    while select task
    join SecurityRole, SecurityTask from srtGrant
    where  srtGrant.SecurityRole == _role.RecId
        && srtGrant.SecurityTask == task.RecId
    {
        nAdded += this.addTask(task);
    }

    if (_recursive)
    {
        while select childRole
        where childRole.RecId != targetRoleId
        join SecurityRole, SecuritySubRole from subRole
        where  subRole.SecuritySubRole == childRole.RecId
            && subRole.SecurityRole    == _role.RecId
        {
            this.addTasksFromRole(childRole, true);
        }
    }
    endLengthyOperation();

    if (added) //Added
            {
                EePersonalDataAccessLogging::logRoleTaskChange(securityTask.RecId,0, securityRole, AddRemove::Add);
            }

    return nAdded;
    }
```

Why doesn’t this trigger the logging?
Do I need to provide any more information?
The `SysSecRoleAddTasks` Form has  also the `addTask` method, I tried it here as well, but this again doesn’t trigger the logtable to be filled.

```
public int addTask(SecurityTask _task, boolean _trialAdd = false)
{
    SecurityRoleTaskGrant srtGrant;
    int nAdded = 0;
    boolean             added; //Added
    RefRecId    securityRole; //Added

    select targetRole
    where targetRole.RecId == targetRoleId; // make sure in sync

    select forupdate srtGrant
    where  srtGrant.SecurityTask == _task.RecId
        && srtGrant.SecurityRole == targetRoleId;

    if (!srtGrant)
    {
        if (!_trialAdd)
        {
            ttsbegin;
            srtGrant.SecurityTask = _task.RecId;
            srtGrant.SecurityRole = targetRoleId;
            srtGrant.insert();
            nAdded++;

            myObjects.insert(_task.RecId, true);

            if (added) //Added
            {
                EePersonalDataAccessLogging::logRoleTaskChange(securityTask.RecId,0, securityRole, AddRemove::Add);
            }

            ttscommit;
        }
        else if (targetRoleId != 0)
        {
            nAdded++;
        }
        //info('Added task "' + _task.Name + '" (' + int2str(appl.ttsLevel()) + ')');
    }
    /*
    else
    {
        info('Not adding task "' + _task.Name + '"');
    } */

    return nAdded;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This question requires a lot of hands-on debugging I would think to solve, which I'm not sure many posters are going to do unfortunately. Have you tried just using the system's database log?

`SecurityRole` and `SecurityTask` are system tables, stored under `\System Documentation\Tables\SecurityRole`, so I didn't know where to find them in the DB log wizard, but I wrote a manual job that I think should work.

I've only tested it with `UserInfo`, which is another system table and it appears to have logged changes correctly.

```
static void AddTablesToDBLog(Args _args)
{    
    void logTable(TableId _tableId, DatabaseLogType _logType)
    {
        DatabaseLog dblog;

        dblog.logTable      = _tableId;
        dblog.logField      = 0;
        dblog.logType       = _logType;
        dblog.insert();
    }

    ttsBegin;
    logTable(tableNum(SecurityRole), DatabaseLogType::Insert);
    logTable(tableNum(SecurityRole), DatabaseLogType::Update);
    logTable(tableNum(SecurityRole), DatabaseLogType::Delete);

    logTable(tableNum(SecurityTask), DatabaseLogType::Insert);
    logTable(tableNum(SecurityTask), DatabaseLogType::Update);
    logTable(tableNum(SecurityTask), DatabaseLogType::Delete);
    ttsCommit;

    SysFlushDatabaseLogSetup::main();

    new MenuFunction(menuitemDisplayStr(SysDatabaseLogSetup), MenuItemType::Display).run(null);
    info("Done");
}
```

Comment: This looks like the solution, but after trying I notice that the database log doesn't track any changes made in these tables. It does show the tables in the front-end database log query, but no rows are added to the logging table. I did add a third table, but I don't think that's the problem. I tried adding/removing/editing existing and new tasks to roles in the front-end and in the AOT, both no changes are being tracked. The table I added is the SecurityRoleTaskGrant.

Comment: Strangely enough it only logs delete actions of Tasks from Roles (so SecurityRoleTaskGrant logs 1 type of action), but it doesn't log added Tasks. SecurityRole and SecurityTask are not logged at all for neither of the actions.

Comment: Do you mean to log `SecurityUserRole`? That's the table that receives the roles that are added/removed from users.

Comment: This is already logged out of the box in a separate table EEUserRoleChangeLog (so not in the DatabaseLog systemtable). What I mean is changing the content of a Role. So removing or adding tasks from roles. This data is saved in the SecurityRoleTaskGrant.systemtable. This is the one that requires logging, since you can give someone a simple role and under water add ALL security rights to that simple role, without anyone knowing...